# Azure Service Bus - Lowering round trip time

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are checking out Azure Service bus to use it as our on premise service bus. We are testing the round trip time and it seems to fluctuate between 10 ms and 2000 ms. On average it is around 100-200ms. There seems to be a warm up time that goes from 2 seconds and moves down to 200ms on higher load.

Is there any way to get a lower average round trip time?

Does it help to use the premium tier?
--> (Edit: Didn't help. With 1 message unit, the average was in fact worse with a premium tier)

**Our setup:**

- Consumer (PC#1)
- Producer (PC#2) (note: These two computers are on the same local network)
- Azure Service Bus (actually on azure)
- Side note/fun fact: Distance 1500km to microsoft data center. Speed of light uses ~10ms round trip.

**Test 1:**

- Message count: 1000 pr minute
- MaxConcurrentCalls: 1
- Operation: Receive and delete message
- Prefetch count: 0
- Start avg. 1-2s
- End avg. 100-200ms
- Output: [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/9HHrv1gf)

Sample output:

```
20; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.5134157+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.7781795+01:00; 264,7638
3; 2017-12-07T11:41:47.4827021+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.8378167+01:00; 1355,1146
14; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.1491488+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.8950421+01:00; 745,8933
0; 2017-12-07T11:41:47.2250519+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:41:48.9518713+01:00; 1726,8194
```

**Test 2:**

- Message count: 1000 pr minute
- MaxConcurrentCalls: 1000
- Operation: Receive and delete message
- Prefetch count: 0
- Start avg. 1-2s
- End avg. 100-200ms (note: with spikes up to 20 seconds)
- Output: [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/iG9pcJfY)

Sample output:

```
4; 2017-12-07T11:43:43.5735023+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:43:44.7905668+01:00; 1217,0645
8; 2017-12-07T11:43:43.8166842+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:43:44.8424773+01:00; 1025,7931
11; 2017-12-07T11:43:43.9990189+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:43:44.8989094+01:00; 899,8905
10; 2017-12-07T11:43:43.9383692+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:43:44.9553891+01:00; 1017,0199
```

**Test 3:**

- Message count: 1000 pr minute
- MaxConcurrentCalls: 1000
- Operation: Receive and delete message
- Prefetch count: 1000
- Start avg. 1-2s (warm up significantly reduced)
- End avg. ~100ms(note: with spikes up to max 4.5 seconds, significantly less spikes)
- Output: [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Rqdg2hKk)

Sample output:

```
11; 2017-12-07T11:54:16.8149682+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:54:17.6029464+01:00; 787,9782
14; 2017-12-07T11:54:16.9967915+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:54:17.6709669+01:00; 674,1754
0; 2017-12-07T11:54:16.0599312+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:54:17.6720080+01:00; 1612,0768
15; 2017-12-07T11:54:17.0578415+01:00; 2017-12-07T11:54:17.6724941+01:00; 614,6526
```

=========================

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;

namespace Sticos.ServiceBus.Client
{
    public class ServiceBusClient
    {
        private readonly string _connectionstring;
        private readonly string _topic;
        private readonly TopicClient _topicClient;

        public ServiceBusClient(string connectionstring, string topic)
        {
            _connectionstring = connectionstring ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionstring));
            _topic = topic ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(topic));
            _topicClient = new TopicClient(_connectionstring, _topic);
        }

        public async Task SendAsync(string message)
        {
            await _topicClient.SendAsync(
                new Message()
                {
                    Body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message + ";" + DateTime.Now.ToString())
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Producer:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Sticos.ServiceBus.Client.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ServiceBusClientTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Producer()
        {
            var serviceBus = new ServiceBusClient("[connectionstring]", "[topic]");

            var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var tasks = new Task[1000];
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    tasks[i] = serviceBus.SendAsync($"{i};{DateTime.Now.ToString("o")}");
                    Thread.Sleep(60);
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            });

            Task.WaitAll(producer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't not to notice that you are using the same client to handle all 1000 messages. That means a single connection is used to push all those messages through. A connection has a certain point at which it won't send more than it can (just like a plumbing pipe). A solution is to have multiple clients that are created from multiple factories. Driving concurrency up to 100 doesn't seem to be resourceful when you have a single connection only.

Comment: The problem is not amount of messages that is sendt. It is the time of sending one message from the producer (PC#2) to the consumer (PC#1). The service bus handled a load of 10 000 messages pr minute just fine. The time for each message to reach the destination was on average 100-200ms. We want that time to be lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premium tier of service bus offers consistent performance, as your namespace will have dedicated resources undisturbed by noisy neighbors. On standard tier, performance fluctuates depending on the overall load on the service as your queues/topics share resources with queues/topics from other customers.

Coming to the time taken for a message to reach consumer from producer, I can tell you that there are no delays or other settings in service bus that introduce delay. Service bus delivers messages as fast as it could. I can't really talk or help about network transmission speeds.

But I think improving the throughput of receiving messages will also lower the average time taken for a message to reach the consumer. btw, you didn't paste the code for consumer here. I would suggest few improvement for you to try. Batching of sends really helps performance. Instead of sending one message per send call, send in batches of 10s or 100s based on message size. Also on the receiver, try to use RECEIVEANDDELETE mode if PEEKLOCK/COMPLETE pattern is not that important to you. And using too many concurrent calls means using too many threads. Try adjusting max concurrent calls and prefetch count values and see how throughput changes.

Also AMQP delivers better performance over NetMessaging or Http. Check your client configuration for the protocol being used and change it to AMQP.

As other answers have suggested, more connections will definitely improve throughput. Simply use more senders and more receivers.

Comment: I tried the premium account with 1 MU and found that the round trip time it took was not adequate for my use. My code is mainly on premise and not in Azure, therefore I concluded with using on premise Rabbit MQ to start with. The Rabbit MQ had around 1-5ms round trip. In the question I calculated the time it took for light (in a straight line) to travel from Dublin to My location and round trip time was 10 ms. Adding in some router hops we could probably double or triple this. With round trip time 40-50 ms I could probably use Azure. But, 200 ms was too much.

Comment: I could probably pay for more MU's but this would come at a hefty price, compared to hosting it on some servers I am renting. Do you have some alternatives? Perhaps, any different ways we could do this? I quickly read something about Azure Stack. Does this have a fully fledged Service Bus?

Answer (score 0):

So if you use Service Bus from on premise, there are a few things which can be done. You can for example deploy into the Azure region which is closest to your own data center.
You can check your round trip time from your DC to the Azure DC and do latency measurements. 
Another thing you could evaluate is using express route to minimize latency. 
Would you mind opening a support request? We can look in the back end and see if we can help you further with within that context.